# Creating Autoincrement on AlphaNumeric in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

My Table:

```
CREATE TABLE USER_DATA
([ID] NVARCHAR(10),[NAME] NVARCHAR(50))
```

My Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROC SP_INSERT_USER
@NAME VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ID NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @IDTEMP INT
SELECT @IDTEMP=MAX(CAST(RIGHT([ID],3) AS INT) ) FROM USER_DATA
SELECT @IDTEMP=CASE WHEN @IDTEMP IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE  @IDTEMP+1 END 
SELECT @ID='RP'+RIGHT(('000'+CAST(@IDTEMP AS VARCHAR(10))),3)
INSERT INTO  USER_DATA VALUES (@ID,@NAME)
END
```

Input:

```
SP_INSERT_USER  'Ajit'
SP_INSERT_USER 'Amit'
```

Output:

```
ID         NAME
---------- --------------------------------------------------
RP001     Ajit
RP002     Amit
```

This code is working fine. But the ID is fixed. It is limited to 3 digits like 001, 002, etc. If it get 1000th employee, it is not displaying properly. Is there any way to make it dynamical without fixing the length?

Comment: Don't do this. just use an `IDENTITY` column. Your presentation layer can append the `RP` and leading zeros if this is necessary. Your `SP_INSERT_USER` procedure is not safe when called concurrently (also avoid the `sp_` prefix as this is reserved for Microsoft system procedures)

Comment: Thanks..but I want the code in sql server..in SP(Stored Procedure)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.USER_DATA
(
      PK INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , ID AS 'PR' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(PK AS VARCHAR(5)), 5)
    , NAME NVARCHAR(50)
)

GO

CREATE PROC dbo.SP_INSERT_USER

    @NAME VARCHAR(50)

AS BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.USER_DATA 
    VALUES (@NAME)

END

GO

EXEC dbo.SP_INSERT_USER 'Ajit'
EXEC dbo.SP_INSERT_USER 'Amit'

SELECT ID, NAME 
FROM dbo.USER_DATA
```

Comment: It will increase upto PR009 correctly. after that it will not increase correctly. that will be PR0010 its wrong. it want to be PR010.... please alter this solution